# php values of one array to key of another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays

```
$arr1 = Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 8
    [3] => xx
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1year
    [6] => 7
)
$arr2 = Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
)
```

I want to create a new array with the values of a2 as keys in $arr1.
My resultant array should be like this

```
$arr3 = Array
(
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 8
    [4] => xx
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 1year
    [7] => 7
)
```

Comment: @Pekka how to `array_combine($arr2, $arr1)`? ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
$arr3 = array_combine($arr2, $arr1);
print_r($arr3);
```

Next time please consult the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) first.

Answer (score 4):

You need [`array_combine`](http://docs.php.net/array_combine).

Answer (score 0):

whats about  looking into php manual? and find [`array_combine($keys, $values)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

Comment: You are very clever to snidely make your point by using a word that is not in the dictionary and a sentence that would make a grammar book curl its pages in horror ;)