# need to map two arrays to one array

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php values of one array to key of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680188/php-values-of-one-array-to-key-of-another-array)

I have the sorted array

```
$A  = array(
            0=>EUR,
            1=>GBP,
            2=>USD
            );

$B =  array(
            0=>'0.88',
            1=>'0'
            );
```

I want to map to be like this allways put `'EUR'=>'1'`:

```
  $C  = array(
        'EUR'=>'1',
        'GBP'=>'0.88',
        'USD'=>'0'
        );
```

Could anyone tell me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$C = array_combine($A, array_merge(array(1), $B));
```

Comment: thanks for your efficient ways.

Answer (score 1):

```
$C = array();
foreach ($A as $key => $value)
{
    $C[$value] = $B[$key];
}
```