# how to replace value of one array to key of another array?

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php values of one array to key of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680188/php-values-of-one-array-to-key-of-another-array)

i have given two array here.

```
Array-1
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 11
            [2] => 13
        )

        Array-2
        (
            [0] => 13.339066309
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 100
        )
```

I want to replace value of one array to key of another array. something like this:

```
Array
    (
        [6] => 13.339066309
        [11] => 0
        [13] => 100
    )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `array_combine`:

```
$new_array = array_combine($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 2):

take a look at [array_combine()](https://www.php.net/array_combine)

$result = array_combine(array_values($firstArr), array_values($secondArr));

Comment: `array_values` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $result[$value] = $array2[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```php
$t = array();
$keys = array_keys($arr1);
for ($i = 0; $i < min(count($keys), count($arr2)); $i++) {
    $t[$keys[$i]] = $arr2[$i];
}
```